# button not showing text inside a nested linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, button, text, display

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:id="@+id/cmdInput"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:ems="8"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:text="@string/cmdInputTxt"  >

                <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            </EditText>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/But"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"

                android:onClick="butC"
                android:text="buttonTxt" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/But2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"

                android:onClick="butC2"
                android:text="buttonTxt2" />


        </LinearLayout>
          
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

why is the button not showing text.  The button is just gray color .  I'm testing on android 10.
I have linearlayout inside a linearlayout.I need  a solution to "no text showing" problem.
I cant use relative because i have two buttons.
I have to use linearlayout for the two buttons.
what are the ways to force buttons text to show.

your help will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you said the height of the buttons are 20dp you should use wrap_content

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/But"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="butC"
            android:text="buttonTxt" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/But2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="butC2"
            android:text="buttonTxt2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

By the way, use SP for the textSize not DP

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```